# Can we call SOAP web service from visual studio 2013 declarative workflow?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, visual-studio-2013, soap

We want to call custom asp.net web service (.Asmx) from visual studio 2013 declarative workflow. So is it possible to call SOAP service using "HttpSend" activity? OR does we need to develop RESTfull service?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint workflows can consume any sort of web service.

You could check the guideline below.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/working-with-web-services-in-sharepoint-workflows-using-visual-studio-2012